# Completely lost on weight. Maybe my code isnt right

Tags: java, android

So with this code I am getting the desirable results where as there are 3 buttons created each time the if statement is executed with an on click. The first button has a var name and takes up the majority of the space. The second 2 buttons, remove and change, are both the same size and small to the right of the name button. However I have my weight set as such:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams newLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams newTroopParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams rmvBtnParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 3.5f);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams chngNameParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 3.5f);
```

I was under the impression that the first button that has the 1f would be the smallest if the number was smaller. Here is my full if statement. Like I said I get desirable results but I would like to further understand this and if I am doing this right or not. Thanks

```
if (count <= 5)
    {
    //CREATE NEW LINEAR LAYOUT
    LinearLayout addTroopLayout = new LinearLayout(this);   

    //CREATE LAYOUT PARAMS FOR LAYOUT
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams newLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    newLayout.bottomMargin = 10;

    //STYLE NEW LINEAR LAYOUT
    addTroopLayout.setId(count);
    addTroopLayout.setLayoutParams(newLayout);
    addTroopLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);     

    //CREATE NEW BUTTONS
    Button newTroop = new Button(this);
    Button remove = new Button(this);
    Button change = new Button(this);

    //CREATE LAYOUT PARAMS FOR BUTTONS
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams newTroopParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams rmvBtnParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 3.5f);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams chngNameParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 3.5f);


    //STYLE NEW BUTTONS
    newTroop.setId(count);
    newTroop.setText(name);
    newTroop.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    newTroop.setLayoutParams(newTroopParam);
    remove.setId(count);
    remove.setText("-");
    remove.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    remove.setLayoutParams(rmvBtnParam);
    change.setId(count);
    change.setText("...");
    change.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    change.setLayoutParams(chngNameParam);

    //ADD VIEWS TO NEW LAYOUT
    addTroopLayout.addView(newTroop);
    addTroopLayout.addView(remove);
    addTroopLayout.addView(change);

    //ADD NEW LAYOUT TO mainPage LAYOUT
    mainPage.addView(addTroopLayout);

    //Increment Counter
    count++;
    }
```

Comment: better use XML for UI part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Arnav M kindly use UI to design. Later you can use the properties to have it in code behind.

Anyway, try changing MATCH_PARENT to WRAP_CONTENT for all Buttons.

So, the code should be:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams newTroopParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams rmvBtnParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 3.5f);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams chngNameParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 3.5f);
```

Comment: Well the reason I wanted to do the majority of it in code is because I want the user to be able to decide how many names they want to enter up to a total of 50 so I didnt want to write 50 linear layouts and then have to set them to invisible and show them as the user needed them. It seemed like it made more sense to do it in java with a onClick if statement. And changing the match to wrap did work. Thanks!

Comment: I can understand your intention but I would suggest to have the UI designed in a test layout and once you have the UI finalized just write code to match/mimic the layout, that way you need not to put too much of visualization in your mind. Anyway all the best for your project.